# Сервер и Thread не уживаются

Tags: c++, сервер, многопоточность

Собираю маленький игровой сервер и никак не мог понять, почему он иногда не работает, почти один и тот же код в разных проектах. И вот методом скурпулезного выколупывания вычислил, что если закоментить <thread>, то сервер работает. Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему? Где конфликт и как с этим бороться?

```
#define MAX_SLOTS 400
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>
//#include <process.h>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "mswsock.lib")

#define PORT 11112
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    WSAData WSADat; // Свойства WinSock (результат функции WSAStartup)
    WSAStartup(0x0202, &WSADat); // Инициализация WinSock
    SOCKET  Socket;

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (!Socket)cout << "soket no create" << endl;
    sockaddr_in socketAddr;
    socketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    socketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    bind(Socket, (struct sockaddr*)&socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr));
    listen(Socket, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKET client_socket;
    sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    int client_addr_size = sizeof(clientAddr);

    // цикл извлечения запросов на подключение из очереди

    while ((client_socket = accept(Socket, (sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &client_addr_size)))
    {
        printf("ghghgf");
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Димка, что значит "не работает"?

Вот ни разу 

     printf("ghghgf");

не отрабатывает? 

Наверное, это какие-то виндовые фокусы. Может, там '\n' надо добавить или `fflish(stdout)` вызвать.

Comment: в коде нигде больше потоки не используются. Поэтому влияние `<thread>` должно быть минимальным. Весь код выполняется в главном потоке, так что ничего не должно меняться.

Возможно, это урезанный код?

Comment: Суть в том, что как раз ни разу и не должен показывать "ghghgf", пока не будет обращение к порту 11112. Но при включенном <thread> гонит эти надписи в цикле.

Да код здесь не весь, я оставил только необходимое для работы сервера. И как раз проблема, если в код включен <THREAD>.

Comment: я бы распечатал значение client_socket внутри цикла. Подозреваю, что оно равно `-1`, то есть, произошла ошибка. А это значит, что нужно дергнуть `WSAGetLastError` и посмотреть результат. А потом сравнить с [известными](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/ms737526(v=vs.85)).

Comment: Стопнул выполнение: client_socket показал 10 - значное число.

Comment: число в студию!

Comment: client_socket 4294967295 unsigned int

Comment: ну так 4294967295 == 0xFFFFFFFF, если бы это было знаковое, то это как раз и был бы -1. Так что мое допущение правильно. accept прерывается по ошибке (а Вы классически не проверяете его:) ). То есть, никакого подключения нет.

Выводите значение `WSAGetLastError` и будем смотреть дальше.

И, если Вас просят назвать число, то не нужно говорить "десятизначное число". Нужно просто его написать. Это экономит время.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Пролог**

В целом, я разобрался с сим безобразием. Нашел рабочую студию и потестил, минут 15 заняло. :)

**Настелим соломки**

В целом да, accept срабатывает, потому что он возвращает -1. WSAGetLastError говорит 10022. Согласно документации это "неверно настроенный сокет, например, пытаемся делать accept на сокете, для которого не сделали listen". Смотрим на listen - он-то вызывается! Но мы-то знаем, что он возвращает -1  в случае ошибки, а ТС не добавил подобных проверок. Добавляем где-то так:

```
int err = listen(Socket, SOMAXCONN);
if (err == -1) {
  int c = WSAGetLastError();
  printf("error = %d\n", c);
  return 1;
}
```

Запускаем. Снова 10022. Комментируем `#include <thread>` - все нормально. Интереснее.

**Страсти накаляются**

Значит, неверно сработал предыдущий вызов функции для сокета. А это bind. Проделаем с ним подобное listen. И тут ждет засада - код не компилируется!!! Но документация утверждает, что там все нормально - [int bind(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Снова комментируем `#include <thread>` -  все работает. Раскомментируем назад. Переходим на функцию bind и жмем F12 (перейти на декларацию функции). Но мы почему-то в модуле functional.

**Виновник найден**

Тут все стает на свои места. Файл thread через вложенные include подтянул functional. А в нем действительно есть функция [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982702.aspx). Да, ее параметры не совсем подходят, но компилятор как-то разрулил.

**Что делать?**

Просто напишите вызов функции двоеточиями в начале:

```
::bind(Socket, (struct sockaddr*)&socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr));
::listen(Socket, SOMAXCONN);
```

Теперь будет вызываться нужная функция.

**Выводы**

Если функция что-то возвращает, всегда проверяйте результат. И все будет хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim, супер.

Comment: @KoVadim, ты крут, ты чертовски крут! :)))))