# Accept не ждёт подключения, если выполняется не в главном потоке

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winsock

Есть следующий код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#define DEFAULT_PORT     htons(444)               // PORT - 23090
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS  inet_addr("127.0.0.1")     // IP ADRESS - 192.0.0.1

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


void sockThreadMain();


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::thread mainTread(sockThreadMain);

    mainTread.join();

    return 0;
}


void sockThreadMain(){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    char  message[4];

    SOCKET sock_Listen;      // Прослушивает подключился сокет или нет
    SOCKET sock_Connection;  // если сокет подключился к прослушивани, соединяется

    ::sockaddr_in ADDRESS;
    int addrLen;

    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = DEFAULT_ADDRESS;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = DEFAULT_PORT;

    addrLen = sizeof(ADDRESS);

    sock_Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sock_Listen, (::SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, addrLen);
    listen(sock_Listen, 5);

start:  if (sock_Connection = accept(sock_Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &addrLen))   //**функция не ждет подключения к прослушивающему сокету и возвращает непонятные цифры. Как решить эту проблему?**
    {
            for (;;)
            {

                cout << "Waiting for massage from client..." << endl;
                cout << "connection was found !" << endl;

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {

                    _itoa_s(rand() % 256, message, 10);  // формирование главного сообщение с числами от 0 до 255   
                    if (SOCKET_ERROR == send(sock_Connection, message, sizeof(message), 0)) goto start;

                }

            }
}

}
```

Функция `accept(sock_Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &addrLen)` не ждет подключения сокета и ничего не возвращает. В аналогичной программе только без потока все работает. В чем может быть проблема? Почему `accept` ничего не возвращает и не ждет подключения?

Comment: в чем именно вопрос?

Comment: @margosh, функция accept(sock_Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &addrLen) не ждет подключения сокета и ничего не возвращает. В аналогичной программе только без потока все работает. В чем проблема? Почему accept ничего не возвращает и не ждет подключения?

Comment: Код написан плохо, поэтому и не видите ошибок.  Добавьте ветку else для if с accept и там сделайте вызов `WSAGetLastError()`. Она возвращает число, которое и расскажет о причинах ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim, WSAGetLastError() возвращает число 10022. Сейчас буду искать что за ошибка и как ее решить.

Comment: здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx - Invalid argument. Обычно это значит, что предыдущие вызовы "сокетных функций" были с ошибками. Например, bind, результат которого Вы также не проверяете.

Comment: @KoVadim, WSAGetLastError() я ставил и после и перед if, ошибка одна и та же. Значит проблема появилась еще до accept.

Comment: @KoVadim, ошибка появляется после listen(sock_Listen, 5) . Но я не понимаю почему, я сделал все точно так же, как и в моей рабочей программе только запихнул это все в поток =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобная проблема уже была и описывалась. Более того, я там сделал детальный разбор - [Сервер и Thread не уживаются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393819/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-thread-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: О БОЖЕ! ты даже не представляешь на сколько сильно ты мне помог!!! спасибо огромное! p.s. я бы , наверное, никогда бы не решил эту проблему и в итоге сошел бы с ума)

Comment: @AndreyGalushka, сходить с ума не надо, а вот принять ответ надо. Нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом

Comment: кстати интересный аргумент не в пользу `using namespace std;`

Comment: @ixSci, нажал. Просто я здесь первый раз и еще не разобрался что да как. using namespace std; - убрал.