# Ошибка: "count" is ambiguous

Tags: c++

**При объявлении *count* глобальной переменной выдает ошибку, но при локали все наоборот. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит?**

> *Пару разу перезапускал VS,а ошибки как-будто и не было.*

[image: Собственно сама ошибка]

Comment: Не используйте картинку, что бы показать код. Это плохо. Не используйте using namespace std, это ещё хуже.

Comment: Не вижу никакой проблемы использовать using namespace std в маленьких программах. По поводу картинки - учту. Спасибо, что ответили на вопрос.

Comment: Использование подобной конструкции очень часто и приводит к указанным проблемам. Но если не видите в этом проблемы - можно ещё раз перезапустить студию, может поможет

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Comment: потому что у Вас ещё в include есть <algorithm> или что то другое, что его включает. А там есть стандартный алгоритм std::count. И когда Вы добавляете using namespace std, то у компилятора появляется два имени и ему это не нравится.

Comment: У меня кроме ввода\вывода(iostream) больше никаких библиотек нет. Дополнено: без using namespace std так же выдавало ошибку,но, после перезапуска среды(2 раза) все пришло в норму.

Comment: Попробовал еще раз с самого начала, только на этот раз без using.Проблема исчезла. Спасибо за помощь. Мне кажется проблема заключалась: либо в стандарте C++, либо в среде VS, т.к. код из книги Герберта Шилдта.

Comment: расписал детальнее. В книгах почти всегда пишут - мы экономим буквы, поэтому, не будем писать (будем вредить)

Comment: Одни стандартные хедеры могут инклудить другие, это разрешено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная проблема - это использование `using namespace std`. Оно подтягивает все доступные (видимые) имена с `std`  в основное пространство имен.

В хедере `algorithm` есть стандартная функция-алгоритм [std::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). И если использовать  `using namespace std`, то она стает доступна по имени count. И компилятор с линковщиком не знает, что делать и кого использовать.

> У меня кроме ввода\вывода(`iostream`) больше никаких библиотек не

я проверил на студийном компиляторе - да, даже при наличии iostream оно как то подтягивает. Как - одному Майкрософту известно.

Что можно сделать? Правильный способ - не использовать using namespace std. А в хедерах даже не думать использовать. Но что если рукам лень писать `std::cout`? - написать `using std::cout;` и будет как нужно.

Но если очень-очень хочется? В данном случае есть обходной путь - глобальную переменную писать вот так

```
std::cout << ::count << "\n";
```

двойное двоеточие подскажет компилятору использовать переменную с глобального пространства имен и ничего не будет плохого.

но что делать, если все ещё уверены в том, что using namespace std (я в этом ответе это написал больше, чем за последний год в своем коде:) ) - это хорошо? почитать мой разбор здесь [Сервер и Thread не уживаются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393819/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8-thread-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f/395196#395196)