# Что делать, если конфликтуют заголовки C++?

Tags: c++, linux, include

В коде применяется вектор и функция reverse (она нужна для реверса строки). Если у меня в коде так:

```
...
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
...
```

то компилятор выдаёт:

```
main.cpp: error: ‘reverse’ was not declared in this scope

reverse(mountstr.begin(), mountstr.end());
```

Эта часть кода "переворачивает" строку mountstr.

Но когда я делаю так:

```
...
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
...
```

то выскакивают ошибки в векторах. Сразу приведу фрагменты кода (там огромный код), чтобы вы понимали, что к чему:

```
struct partition {
    unsigned int major;
    unsigned int minor;
    string blkdev;
    string name;
};
```

```
vector<partition> partinfo;
.....
partinfo.at(blks).major = stoi(uline);
```

А вот и ошибка:

```
main.cpp: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  145 |         vector<partition> partinfo;
      |                         ^
main.cpp:145:25: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:161:34: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘partinfo’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  161 |                         partinfo.at(blks).major = stoi(uline);
      |                                  ^~
```

Да, вы не ослышались, тут натурально конфликт заголовков. Я даже пробовал убирать `using namespace std;` (говорят, не очень хорошая практика объявлять так std), дописал std:: куда надо - ровно эта же проблема никуда не делась.

*Эх, если бы в C++ можно было подтянуть только одну функцию из импорта, как в python...*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137017/discussion-on-question-by-randomdice-779-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `using namespace std;` и никаких конфликтов не будет если соблюдать одно правило: не использовать имена определённые в стандартных заголовках включённых в файл. Например для кода ...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
```

... вам нужно избегать использования в коде следующих имён `adjacent_find`,
`all_of`,
`any_of`,
`begin`,
`binary_search`,
`clamp`,
`common_comparison_category`,
`compare_partial_order_fallback`,
`compare_strong_order_fallback`,
`compare_three_way`,
`compare_three_way_result`,
`compare_weak_order_fallback`,
`copy`,
`copy_backward`,
`copy_if`,
`copy_n`,
`count`,
`count_if`,
`end`,
`equal`,
`equal_range`,
`fill`,
`fill_n`,
`find`,
`find_end`,
`find_first_of`,
`find_if`,
`find_if_not`,
`for_each`,
`for_each_n`,
`generate`,
`generate_n`,
`hash`,
`includes`,
`initializer_list`,
`inplace_merge`,
`is_eq`,
`is_gt`,
`is_gteq`,
`is_heap`,
`is_heap_until`,
`is_lt`,
`is_lteq`,
`is_neq`,
`is_partitioned`,
`is_permutation`,
`is_sorted`,
`is_sorted_until`,
`iter_swap`,
`lexicographical_compare`,
`lexicographical_compare_three_way`,
`lower_bound`,
`make_heap`,
`max`,
`max_element`,
`merge`,
`min`,
`min_element`,
`minmax`,
`minmax_element`,
`mismatch`,
`move`,
`move_backward`,
`next_permutation`,
`none_of`,
`nth_element`,
`partial_order`,
`partial_ordering`,
`partial_sort`,
`partial_sort_copy`,
`partition`,
`partition_copy`,
`partition_point`,
`pop_heap`,
`prev_permutation`,
`push_heap`,
`random_shuffle`,
`ranges`,
`remove`,
`remove_copy`,
`remove_copy_if`,
`remove_if`,
`replace`,
`replace_copy`,
`replace_copy_if`,
`replace_if`,
`reverse`,
`reverse_copy`,
`rotate`,
`rotate_copy`,
`sample`,
`search`,
`search_n`,
`set_difference`,
`set_intersection`,
`set_symmetric_difference`,
`set_union`,
`shift_left`,
`shift_right`,
`shuffle`,
`sort`,
`sort_heap`,
`stable_partition`,
`stable_sort`,
`strong_order`,
`strong_ordering`,
`swap`,
`swap_ranges`,
`three_way_comparable`,
`three_way_comparable_with`,
`transform`,
`unique`,
`unique_copy`,
`upper_bound`,
`vector`,
`weak_order`,
`weak_ordering` и, возможно, некоторых других.

В вашем случае вы использовали имя `partition` а оно уже занято.

Лучше контролировать имена в глобальном пространстве используя их по одному:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::reverse, std::vector;
```

**P.S.** После `using namespace std;` вы не знаете какие имена заняты. Даже если вы думаете что знаете, другой компилятор задействует другие имена и ваш код радикально и не заметно для вас изменит смысл. Тоже произойдёт когда вы обновите версию C++. Особенно трудно с реализацией шаблонов. Не надо так делать. Не импортируйте пространства имён, импортируйте отдельные символы.

**P.P.S.** По просьбе [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) воспроизвожу ошибку:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct partition { };
struct test_t { vector<partition> partinfo; };
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.cpp 
> temp.cpp:9:33: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>     9 | struct test_t { vector<partition> partinfo; };
>       |                                 ^
> temp.cpp:9:33: error: template argument 2 is invalid
> ```

Comment: Да можно эти имена использовать. Главное делать это правильно. Да, местами нужно struct дописать, местами :: поставить, но можно.

Comment: Кажется, я не сумел донести основную мысль: если делать `using namespace std;` нет способа определить какие имена получили значения, какие это значения и можно ли их перекрыть определением ниже.

Comment: я на using namespace std съел не одну собаку. Все можно сделать, но мне хотелось воспроизвести именно ситуацию автора вопроса. Но похоже никто нее не воспроизводил

Comment: @KoVadim, посмотрите исправленный ответ. Это то что вы ищете?

Comment: да. я понял, почему я ее не видел. потому что я тестил на clang и vs. А в gcc нет. И вот оказывается, что только gcc выдает такую ошибку. Очень интересно.

Comment: Кстати, если писать вот так `vector<struct partition> partinfo;` или вот так `vector<::partition> partinfo;`, то using namespace std; можно обойти. Некоторые мои знакомые судорожно ставят двоеточия даже перед std. Вот мой связанный с этим ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393819/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8-thread-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f/395196#395196

Comment: @KoVadim, можно, вы это блестяще показали. Но чем можно оправдать необходимость проверять использование **каждого** имени?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю вопрос

Comment: `using namespace std;` может незаметно для программиста изменить смысл кода ниже. Код должен быть протестирован. Если `using` в заголовке, а перед заголовком в разных файлах включены разные стандартные заголовки, может нарушиться ODR. Компилятор не поможет, разный порядок линковки может привести к различному поведению той же самой программы.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря Stanisval Volodarsky я сделал так:

```
namespace emmc {
struct partition {
    unsigned int major;
    unsigned int minor;
    string blkdev;
    string name;
};
};
```

и

```
vector<emmc::partition> partinfo;
```

Comment: Да, все красивые имена функций и типов уже разобраны... Вскоре тоже самое случится с именами namespace

Comment: "двойные namespace вошли в чат": `std::__fs::filesystem::exists()`